# In Microsoft Excel: How do I minus a total in a cell, when other cells change colour?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a finances tracker. I have a cell with a 'Total Balance Left' on a loan.
I made a table for each month.
In that table, for each month I have a drop down that I change from Pending to Done.
The cell changes colour from grey to blue when it's set as Done.

I am hoping to create a simple minus formula so the 'Total Balance Left' cell will auto update, reducing the number everytime I change a cell to 'Done'.

Does that make sense? I can provide a screenshot if that's easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You write a function in VBA that is called from the cell you want that does the subtraction operation.

Comment: The difficulty here is to permit for a reverse change, i.e. to show the correct total if the user changes from *Done* to *Pending*. So, when that cell changes a complete recalculation of the total must be done, considering the original loan amount, installments paid to-date, the amount now due and the status of the validated cell. The task is probably only insignificantly smaller if a reverse can be effectively prevented. However, the color of that cell is totally irrelevant.